# ListView method trigged in wrong position

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have the listview, contain checkbox,and textview, When isCheck then I will change color of this View and TextView. But wrong position. Please tell me why? Many thanks

```
public class GLPSelectFlight extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private Button btnContinue;
private TextView tvHeader;
private LinearLayout linBack;
private ListView lvSelectFlight;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_glpselect_flight);
    initView();
}

private void initView() {

    linBack = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.home);
    linBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    linBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    tvHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
    tvHeader.setSingleLine(true);
    tvHeader.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
    tvHeader.setText(getString(R.string.SELECT_FLIGHT));

    lvSelectFlight = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvGlpShowFlightInfo);
    adapter = new GLPShowFlightAdapter();
    lvSelectFlight.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnContinue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContinue);
    btnContinue.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvFlightName;
    RelativeLayout rllFlightName;
    CheckBox cb;
}

GLPShowFlightAdapter adapter;
ViewHolder holder;

// for temporary Adapter.
private class GLPShowFlightAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public GLPShowFlightAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(GLPSelectFlight.this)
                    .inflate(R.layout.glp_list_flight, parent, false);

            holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.cbSelectFlight);
            holder.rllFlightName = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rllFlightName);
            holder.tvFlightName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvFlightName);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Log.e("", "checked in pos : " + position);
                    holder.tvFlightName.setText("POS :" + position);
                    holder.rllFlightName.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                } else {
                    Log.e("", "unchecked in pos : " + position);
                    holder.tvFlightName
                            .setText("returned POS :" + position);
                    holder.rllFlightName.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        break;
    case R.id.btnContinue:
        Intent in = new Intent(new Intent(GLPSelectFlight.this,
                TranferBonusPaymentActivity.class));
        startActivity(in);
        break;
    }
}
```

}

[image]
I upload the image, When I Click to the ComboBox, this log say the exact position ( It's OK). But the event I write happen in other pos. 
Above is my adapter, all component were find from layout (no problem).

Comment: I check in combo box position 0,1,2, no thing happend, but in 3 - trigged in pos 4,  and in comboBox in pos 4 cause this trigged in pos 0.

Comment: which position you are getting when you click on list item? I mean check for the position inside getView()

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with your getView. Basically your codes are right but you need to do some steps more. Issue is your items are recycling.

I guess your ListView is multi selection so going with ArrayList.

**Step 1:**

Declare an arrayList
ArrayList id_array = new ArrayList();

**Step 2:**

Change arrayList like this

```
holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn,
                    boolean isChecked) {
               if (!id_array.contains(holder.cb.getId())){
//add id to your arraylist
}else{
//Remove id from arrayList
}

            }
        });
```

Following codes need to write outside of oncheckedchangeListener

```
 if (id_array.contains(holder.cb.getId())){
                    Log.e("", "checked in pos : " + position);
                    holder.tvFlightName.setText("POS :" + position);
                    holder.rllFlightName.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                } else {
                    Log.e("", "unchecked in pos : " + position);
                    holder.tvFlightName
                            .setText("returned POS :" + position);
                    holder.rllFlightName.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
```

**NOTE:**
And i go through your code you don't use setId for checkbox. I hope you must have some ID set that is to checkBox. Then only my piece of code will work

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return null;
}
```

with

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Meenaxi for getting object you can't return position, there is another method for that

Answer (score 0):

the 'holder' reference should be inside the getView() function.. not sure that's it, but it might be.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that way can solve this problem. Just use data and pass it to adapter. When event trigged, change data and call notifidatasetchanged().

```
public class GLPSelectFlight extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button btnContinue;
    private TextView tvHeader;
    private LinearLayout linBack;
    private ListView lvSelectFlight;
    private int[] data = new int[] { Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE,
            Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_glpselect_flight);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {

        linBack = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.home);
        linBack.setOnClickListener(this);
        linBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        tvHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
        tvHeader.setSingleLine(true);
        tvHeader.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
        tvHeader.setText(getString(R.string.SELECT_FLIGHT));

        lvSelectFlight = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvGlpShowFlightInfo);
        adapter = new GLPShowFlightAdapter(data);
        lvSelectFlight.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnContinue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContinue);
        btnContinue.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvFlightName;
        RelativeLayout rllFlightName;
        CheckBox cb;
    }

    GLPShowFlightAdapter adapter;
    ViewHolder holder;

    // for temporary Adapter.
    private class GLPShowFlightAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private int[] data;

        public GLPShowFlightAdapter(int[] data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getItem(int pos) {
            return data[pos];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int pos) {
            return pos;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(GLPSelectFlight.this)
                        .inflate(R.layout.glp_list_flight, parent, false);

                holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.cbSelectFlight);
                holder.cb.setId(position * 69);
                holder.rllFlightName = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.rllFlightName);
                holder.tvFlightName = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvFlightName);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        Log.e("", "checked in pos : " + position);
                        data[position] = Color.BLUE;
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        Log.e("", "unchecked in pos : " + position);
                        data[position] = Color.WHITE;
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.rllFlightName.setBackgroundColor(data[position]);
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            break;
        case R.id.btnContinue:
            Intent in = new Intent(new Intent(GLPSelectFlight.this,
                    TranferBonusPaymentActivity.class));
            startActivity(in);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**BUT I CAN NOT KNOW ABOVE QUESTION : WHY THIS PROBLEM APPEAR. IF SOMEONE KNOW PLEASE TELL ME. THANKS :)**